# MYSQL - Update values of new column based on condition

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

I have the following table

```
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| image_id     | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| image_status | bit(3)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| image_result | varchar(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

image_id and image_status columns are populated with values. The values in image_result are all NULL.

I want to insert the following values into the image_result column based on the following conditions (I want to update all the rows in the table)-

- if image_status = '0' OR image_status = '3' then image_result =
  'Pass'
- if image_status = '1' OR image_status = '4' then image_result =
  'Warn'
- if image_status = '2' then image_result = 'Fail'

How do I do the above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UPDATE table 
SET image_result = CASE 
    WHEN image_status = 0 OR image_status = 3 THEN 'Pass' 
    WHEN image_status = 1 OR image_status = 4 THEN 'Warm' 
    ELSE 'Fail' 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE TableName
SET image_result = CASE 
                     WHEN image_status = '0' OR image_status = '3' THEN 'PASS'  
                     WHEN image_status = '1' OR image_status = '4' THEN 'Warn' 
                     WHEN image_status = '2' THEN 'Fail'
                   END
WHERE image_status IN('0', '1', '2', '3', '4');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update <table> set image_result = 
Case when image_status = '0' OR image_status = '3' then 'Pass'
     when image_status = '1' OR image_status = '4' then 'Warn'
     when image_status = '2'                       then 'Fail'
End
```